# Create array GameObject Background

Tags: unity-game-engine

i am trying to create a gameobject array of 4 backgr.
Every time you pass the screen, you will change to another backgr. I don't know where I'm going wrong, please help

```
    public GameObject[] Backgrounds;
    public SpriteRenderer BakcgrRenderer;
    public Vector2 BackgrSize { get => mapRenderer.size; }
    public void ChangeBackgr(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        BackgrRenderer.sprite = Backgrounds[(int)id];
    }
```

Comment: afaik in general you don't simply cast nullables but you rather access `id.Value` .... do you get any errors?

Comment: Backgrounds[(int)id]; cannot convert type 'UnityEngine.GameObject' to 'UnityEngine.Sprite'

Comment: what do you not understand about the error message? You have a bunch of `GameObject` and try to assign it to `BackgrRenderer.sprite` which rather expects a `Sprite` ...

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: we can't tell .. what exactly are you trying to do? Are you just trying to enable and disable a certain background? -> Use `SetActive` and remove that `BackgrRenderer` part. Or are you trying to assign something to `BackgrRenderer.sprite`? -> Don't use `GameObject[]` but a `Sprite[]` ...

Comment: i am trying to create a gameobject array of 4 backgr. Every time i pass the screen, i will change to another backgr. What should I do?

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Dictionary, You can use an ID and a Value, After that you can set a gameobjet from the Dictionary by doing this,

```
a.Add(Id, Value);
```

and for getting the value :

```
GameObject g;
a.TryGetValue(Id, out g);
if (g != null)
{
// code here
}
```

for this Dictionary I use this :

```
Dictionary<string, GameObject>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to assign a game Object to the value of a sprite.

Instead of

```
BackgrRenderer.sprite = Backgrounds[(int)];
```

You need to access the sprite from the gameObject and assign that

```
BackgrRenderer.sprite = Backgrounds[(int)].sprite;
```